A movie about a Magician
This was a movie I saw a couple of years ago on TV so some of the details I give might not be the case. 
The movie starts off with a stage magician. After the show, a friend visits him and asks him how he does the trick, and the magician goes on telling him a back story describing how he came to get magic powers. 
In the back story, the magician gets his powers from an Indian. I remember a scene in which the Indian tells the magician to make a building disappear and the magician blinks and makes it disappear. I believe the magician's name was Harry Houdini

Hard to tell exactly, but it's similar to Young Harry Houdini (1987), a Disney made-for-TV movie.

This biographical movie depicts the youth of the magician Harry
  Houdini (1874 - 1926). As a boy his name was Eric Weiss and his father
  wanted him to become a locksmith. But he ran away and joined the
  traveling show of Dr. Grimaldi, where he learned the tricks of a
  magician and a little mystery from his Indian assistant, too.

